# Overriding containers CSS behavior

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a Javascript based element that can be embedded into websites. The Javascript itself adds the HTML code into a pre-defined HTML container and dynamically loads the necessary CSS file that contain the element's visual definitions.

The problem starts when the site itself has its own definitions for general items. For example: The site's CSS defines a certain list style which is applied on the element's list because the element's CSS doesn't define an explicit list style or if the site's CSS overrides the element's CSS definition.

For the time being, I was able to solve this specific issue by explicitly defining the list's style and adding the !important definition. However, I would definitely want to go for a more robust solution that will assure that:
1. CSS definitions from the site's CSS that are not explicitly defined in the element's CSS will not be applied on the element
2. I will not need to explicitly add the !important definition to every one of my CSS definitions

Is there a general way in which I can specify that a site's CSS will not be applied on a certain element or that only a certain CSS will be applied to a specific element?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess using an iframe is not an option?

Comment: iframe can be an option but from what i know an iframe would not stop the elements inside it inheriting css rules from the container's css files

Comment: sure it would. The content of an iFrame is completely uncoupled from its containing page.

Comment: @roberkules +1 I agree an iFrame is probably the best approach

Comment: @roberkules I ended up using an iframe and everything works just great. If you wanna open an official answer I'll tag it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You need to use a *localised reset*.

Grab an existing CSS reset, such as [Eric Meyer's Reset Reloaded](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/) and namespace all the selectors with your parent element, e.g. `#something a { ... }`.

Comment: +1 yep I got halfway through writing that when "1 new answer has been posted popped up" :)

Comment: Thanks alex, what makes the the Reset Reloaded override every definition from the site's CSS? From what i saw it doesn't explicitly define every property for every selector, or does it? Also, what will make it the overruling css?

Comment: @tutipute - It makes it overrule the other CSS because of its specificity, as mentioned by Alex (you have to edit the reset to do this). You name the container of the element you want to override with the `id` property, then use that as the starting point to restyle everything inside it.

Answer (score 4):

*I was going to put up the same answer as Alex, but he beat me - but I was also going to add:*

If you're not going to use @alex's suggestion then ultimately you have to explicitly style all of your elements the way that you want them to appear; using selectors that keep your styles local too (and don't interfere with the parent site) - in the same way that the localised reset is suggested.

## Update

Or you could do what Google Translate and many other widget-type things do, usually a no-no but in dynamic scenarios I think perfectly acceptable; since the visual style of your elements is not just important to you but to the container site: use inline styles.

*Final update*

So I thought I'd just double check what Google Translate does.  And of course it's an iFrame inject *in addition to* using inline styles.  They no doubt use inline styles to maximise compatibility and so that the browser doesn't have to make another request to get the stylesheet; and they would be using an iFrame so they can ensure a consistent look and feel.

Consider both of those points in tandem - and weigh that up against the amount of work that might be required in resettting all the styles for a minority portion of the page; or defining rules for every CSS property you need to control - which, let's face it, is basically *all* visual CSS properties.

The iFrame solution actually seems to offer the best solution - if you can use it; hence I've +1'd the first comment by @roberkules on your question.

Comment: I do feel that this solution is cleaner and more straight forward. So if I'll add selectors to all my elements would it prevent them from inheriting css rules from the site's CSS?

Comment: @tutipute: It should do - because CSS will take a rule from `#a .b` over `.b` any day of the week without `!important` tags.
Where it might get interesting is in those rare occasions where somebody has an exact-same selector or even one more 'selective'.
The rules will have to address every CSS property that's important to you with values (e.g. if `margin` is important, then you have to define `margin` so as to prevent the container site killing it)

Comment: Thanks Andras, the problem is that every property is "important to me" because the properties that i didn't have to explicitly define in my CSS (because the default value was good) might be defined in the site's css. So I'll end up defining all the default values for all the selectors

Comment: Andras, how will inline styles help me to avoid the need to explicitly define every property on every element in order to make sure that default values will be used?

Comment: @tutipute - Sorry for delay. It won't but in my opinion it actually makes things simpler because you're keeping everything together at design and runtime. That said, my example of Google Translate - they use a script inject to render an iFrame, thus they have full control without style inheritance.

Comment: @tutipute - have updated my answer again after examining how gTranslate works. Not saying that either of the previous solutions are null and void, but you might save yourself a lot of headache by going the iFrame route instead.